# Proper terminology, should I say indexes or indices?

Tags: indexing, terminology, indices

I had a question about indices on a table and I put it up on Stack Overflow.  I got my answer, but someone changed the word `indices` to say `indexes`.

We know that the plural of `Index` is `Indices`, but we also know that almost everybody prefers the "wrong" word.

What are some other "wrong" terms like this that *really shouldn't be*, but **are** overtaking their "correct" counterparts?

Comment: For a while at one company, some of us tried using "mutices". Didn't really catch on, perhaps because we didn't have the guts to do it in documentation, but I feel the effort was worthwhile ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question but an English question

Comment: The answer is Indicies.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Most people don't know that "[data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data)" is the plural and "datum" is the singular.  How often have you heard "a single data point?"

But then again, even those of us who do know think it sounds goofy and hardly ever say it.

Language is mutable and "datum" might be on its way to becoming archaic by popular decree!

Comment: Adding to the confusion, for Germans like me, is that "data" is commonly used here, and "datum" is just as obscure as in anglophonic countries - but "datum" also means "date" in German...

Comment: DevSolar, and "data" means "date" in Russian ;-) and Polish to stick to Latin charset :)

Comment: I thought that "anecdote" was singular, and "data" was plural

Comment: DevSolar and hacker, that is interesting to know.  Thank you for posting that.

Comment: actually "data point" is perfectly valid; it's an alternate way of writing "point of data". As in, "data" is the composition of the "point". "Datum point" would be redundant and weird.

Comment: The comparison isn't "a single data point" vs. "a single datum point", but "a single data point" vs. "a [single] datum". "Datum" does have other meanings though, e.g. in geodesy, although the term "geodetic datum" is frequently used.

Comment: I think a "a single data point" is correct since it is the point representing the spatial vector having at least one component (datum). Here, "space" has generic meaning: coordinate, sample,  hypotheses, representation etc. space. Returning to indices vs indexes, the OED recommends using plural indexes when referring to directory listings etc. : "the indexes (keys) of a database table" . In math context, plural indices is more appropriate e.g. "the covariate indices of a tensor" .

Answer (score 37):

"Indices" is the mathematical formulation whereas in publishing they use "indexes" (which is probably why so many people in IT consider "indices" to be more correct than "indexes").

I  think that a table index is analogous to an index in a book rather than an exponent in maths, so the publishing variant is the appropriate plural to use in this context.

Furthermore, at least in Oracle, the data dictionary views are called DBA_INDEXES, ALL_INDEXES and USER_INDEXES.  It is usually a good idea to employ the same terminology which the domain uses.

Comment: "Index" in programming can also mean an array index, which is precisely the mathematical use rather than the publishing one. Interesting point, though, perhaps for full pedantry mode we should be demanding always "database indexes" but "array indices" :-)

Comment: The OQ did specifically mention "indices on a table" so I think my point stands.  But if I ever come across an array with more than one index I shall strive to use "indices" when discussing it ;-)

Comment: Mysql docs say indexes https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html, so does postgres docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/indexes.html

Answer (score 21):

Summarizing answers here and elsewhere:

Both are widely used as the plural of *index* in English. The Latinate *indices* is more prevalent in scientific and mathematical contexts, as in the (subscripted) indices of array in a formula. But *indexes* appears to be on the rise, relatively stronger in publishing ('periodical indexes') and American English.

Some see a value in using *indices* uniquely for the plural of the noun *index*, as opposed to the 3rd-person singular present tense *indexes* of the verb *index*. ("He indexes all the TPS reports, you can find those indices in the circular file.")

Some perceive a small shading of difference between simple numerical-offset array *indices* and the more sophisticated data structures of database *indexes* or full-text *indexes*. ("The indexes were corrupted because the update code has an off-by-one error in its indices.")

These distinctions are sufficiently subtle that they're likely only maintainable within a tight-knit community of practice which documents & enforces their preferences, as if in some local & authoritative style guide.

Specifically when naming variables in code:

Using `indexes` has the often-desirable property that a simple *grep* search for `index` will also find that pluralization. When looking for indirect ways in which the same offsets might be referenced, that can be helpful.

```
target_index = 0
indexes[target] = 0
indexes['target'] = 0
target = len(indexes)
```

`indices` doesn't have this property, so I prefer to use `indexes` in code.

Comment: TLDR: In variable naming inside of code, if you use `indexes`, searching `index` will find both `indexes` and `index`. Whereas `indices` doesn't have this property.

Answer (score 11):

[According to webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/index), both "indexes" and "indices" are correct; "indexes" is listed first.

That said, since "indices" was entirely correct to begin with, I don't really think it was appropriate to edit it and replace it with "indexes".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001366/indexes-or-indices/1001379#1001379

Answer (score 2):

How about a reverse answer:

Too many people stubbornly (or maybe pendantically, or ignorantly?) insist on using the word "Octopi." "Octopus" originates from Greek, so the whole "`us` to `i`" for plurals paradigm doesn't exist. Some folks will even correct you if you say "octopuses," which is the correct English plural.

Not to judge, but I notice the folks who say 'octopi' are generally the same ones who insist on 'datum' and 'indeces' ;)

Comment: Actually its octopodes. A good discussion on this over at XKCD: http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=611

Comment: It's octopodes if you happen to be speaking Greek. It's octopuses if you're speaking English.

Comment: Now, if you're planning on going whole hog and applying the appropriate case (http://u.nu/5xh53) you could make a stronger argument for using 'octopodes' instead of 'octopuses.' 'Octopodes' on it's own is just pedantic.

Answer (score 2):

This has been discussed on other places as well. The [English Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61080/plural-of-index-indexes-or-indices) cites the Oxford Dictionary to explain that both is valid:

> plural of index: indexes or especially in technical use indices
>
> The plural of index is usually spelled indexes, but can also be spelled indices (as in the original Latin) in subjects like science and medicine.

[This page makes a good](https://federalist.wordpress.com/2006/09/28/grammar-indexes-vs-indices/) point by suggesting to use "Indices" as plural for the noun to distinguish it from the verb.

**Summary**

So all up I would say in technical context and writing - which is closer to science - and to distinguish it from the verb "**Indices**" is preferred in database speak.

Answer (score 2):

Collins accepts both (http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/index) but in the French-English dictionnary (http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/index), it uses

- *indexes* for the tool at the end of a book (i.e. the collection of pointers to page numbers)
- *indices* for an indicator (e.g. a stock exchange index)

[grammarist.com](http://grammarist.com/usage/indexes-indices) considers *indexes* as the North-American variant.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a continuation of the kilobyte/megabyte/gigabyte discussion. The English language is continuously evolving, and a dictionary isn't a book of rules to be followed, its a snapshot of how the language is used at that point in time. If we chose to use a word differently, then Webster better keep up.

Comment: What is "the kilobyte/megabyte/gigabyte discussion"? Those words cannot mean the same thing like indexes and indices can.

Comment: @cambunctious that would likely be the difference between kibibyte/mebibyte/gibibyte vs kilobyte/megabyte/gigabyte.  The scientific prefixes kilo-/mega-/giga-/etc being defined 10^3/10^6/10^9/... vs the binary prefixes of kibi-/mebi-/gibi-/etc being defined as 2^10/2^20/2^30/...  The debate is seen between OS makers historically used kilo-/etc with the  2^* definitions while hard drive makers have been using 10^* definitions.  Which is why your 500GB hard drive registers as 465GB to the OS. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix

Answer (score 0):

Indices (coming from Latin) are used in scientific work, but
otherwise indexes are used. So the use of indexes is correct
in this case.

From *[Indexes versus indices](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-ind2.htm)* (my emphasis):

> ... the ***standard English way*** of marking the plural, using -s or -es, has progressively been ***taking over*** ...This is why we now prefer crematoriums to the Latin crematoria and forums to fora, though the Latin plurals are still regularly used by some writers.
>
> Indices has ***survived in scientific work***, especially in mathematics. ... ***The usual plural is indexes***, which first appeared in the seventeenth century.